When should I replace the battery in my 5-year-old iPhone 11?
I’ve been using my iPhone 11 for more than 5 years as my daily phone for communication and work, and it’s still performing well. However, I know that phone batteries have a limited lifespan due to chemical aging. The battery health has declined, but I can still get around 12 hours of use.
I’m concerned that the battery might affect the LCD since the phone sometimes gets hot.
Should I replace the battery soon?

Welcome to Ask Different. What does "Battery Health" in Settings > Battery say? If you see Service next to it, you should replace your battery to restore full performance and capacity.

5 years is a good innings. Apple should continue to support battery replacements on that phone until 2027, so there's no rush, but it might give the phone a bit more useful life.

I have never heard of a degraded battery damaging a device. That is the actual question here and should be asked explicitly.

The phone will give you a suggestion on when to do this.
Goto Settings->Battery->Battery Health & Charging
There is a line Maximum Capacity - if it goes below a certain level (70% I think) that page will also show an indicator to say the phone needs servicing.
From Apple the screen will look like


The battery will not damage the screen unless it starts to swell. Keep using it until it feels like it's not lasting long enough or until you get a prompt to replace it, as noted by others.
